# Folder size discrepancy

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, file-management

This is a bit weird.  I have a particular folder that reports: 12,274 Files, 806 Folders when i right click and go in properties. and 12,164 Files, 791 Folders if I do Ctrl-A and do properties in the folder itself.  This folder is actually a backup mirror from another drive so I know the smaller number is correct.  The source folder does Not have a discrepancy between folder/content sizes.  Any Idea's where the extra 110 files are? nothing finds them and its a weird 78GB file usage that doesn't seem to exist.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hidden and or System files?

Comment: as @DavidPostill says: the folder dialog reports about 100 more files and about 15 more folders, so they are hidden or you haven't selected them all (or there is a "symbolic link" [not a shortcut] in there somewhere: explorer can double-report files if two links point to the same file...)